How can I find the WCF Service call issue
Please click here - Exception image I am posting the data to SAP service from C# code, throwing the "Server error". Please help me to fix the issue.
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ShMM.SAPPostData.ZMD_UPDATE.ZMD_UPDATE(ZMD_UPDATERequest request)

Please help me to post the data to service without any issue.

I think you need to add further on this question. At this point, we can only speculate on the issues: 1. Make sure that your SAP service endpoints and associated bindings are configured correctly. Check whether the WCF configuration items in the web.config or app.config file, especially the bound configurations (such as basicHttpBinding, wsHttpBinding, etc.), meet the requirements of SAP services. 2. Deploy the security log file:Tracing and Message Logging

Same code is working on QA environment but not on production environment, Unable to find the exact issue.
